# How do I add a namespace prefix to XElement

Tags: xml, f#

I know about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx. I have read the examples article. But in F# that have some troubles with String to XName conversion. Some code I trying to use:

```
let ( !! ) : string -> XName = XName.op_Implicit


> XElement(!!"tmp:" + !!"root", !!"Content");; 
stdin(9,21): error FS0001: The type 'XName' does not support any operators named '+'

> XElement(!!("tmp:" + "root"), !!"Content");;
System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

> XElement("tmp" + "root", "Content");;   
The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'XName'
```

What I want:

```
<tmp:root>Content</tmp:root>
```

---

UPD:
I want only prefix namespace before tag, like that:

```
<tmp:root>Content</tmp:root>
```

No something like that:

```
> let ns = XNamespace.Get "http://tmp.com/";; 

val ns : XNamespace = http://tmp.com/

> let xe = XElement(ns + "root", "Content");;

val xe : XElement = <root xmlns="http://tmp.com/">Content</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a namespace for this to work.
Try something like this:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll";;
open System.Xml.Linq

let ns = "tmp" |> XNamespace.Get
let ( !! ) : string -> XName = XName.op_Implicit

let rt = !!("blank")

let urlset = new XElement(rt,
                          new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tmp",ns ),
                          new XElement( ns + "root","Content"))
```

Output:

```
val urlset : XElement =
<blank xmlns:tmp="tmp">
   <tmp:root>Content</tmp:root>
</blank>
```

Comment: Ok, "let urlset = new XElement(ns + "blank","... because I don't need a blank node)

Answer (score 2):

What I typically do is...

```
let xmlns = XNamespace.Get

let ns = xmlns "http://my.namespace/"

XElement(ns + "root", "Content")
```

Also I tend not to worry about the difference between two different ways of formatting namespaces in the string output. It all means the same thing to an XML parser.

Comment: >difference between two different ways of formatting namespaces [br] Prefix ns and separate ns? I want only prefix, it's not only my xml format that I use

Comment: The xmlns attribute with the URL and a prefix definition has to exist on a parent node before you can create a child node with only the prefix. [This question describes how to do this using LINQ to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748003/linq-to-xml-and-namespace-prefixes).

Comment: @JoelMueller: Given that he specifically asked for a prefix, you may want to update your answer to include that link.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is define an extra function for each namespace:

```
let (!!) = XName.op_Implicit

let tmp = 
    let ns = XNamespace.op_Implicit "www.temp.com"
    fun n -> XNamespace.op_Addition (ns, n)

XElement (tmp "root", "Content")
```

Alternatively, you can create a function that takes care of a ':' in the name:

```
let xn (name : String) =
    match name.IndexOf ':' with
    | -1 -> XName.op_Implicit name
    |  i -> XNamespace.op_Addition (XNamespace.Get (name.Substring (0, i)), name.Substring (i + 1))

XElement (xn "tmp:test", "Content")
```

Comment: This creates a some like "<Документ Версия="0.1" xmlns="www.TVZ.com" />". I want to "<NS:Документ ..."